# oracle: query to have as output scale and precision for numeric columns - field datatype = number

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, scale, precision

I have a column with number datatype. In this column I have values with scale and precision but also only scale is available.
I would like when i query the data to have in the output scale and precision for all the fields.

`create table test
(
column number
);`

```
insert into test values (123);
insert into test values (0);
insert into test values (15.06);
insert into test values (78.78);
insert into test values (12.3);
commit;
```

### column

```
   123
     0
 15.06
 78.78
  12.3
```

when I query the data I would like to have an output as:

### column

```
123.00
  0.00
 15.06
 78.78
 12.30
```

Can you indicate how should i write the query in order to have the above output? The output should be also numeric. The precision part is not fixed.

Comment: So you want to [format a number](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-291CA766-0B7D-4336-954A-B8A23036F6ED)?

Answer (score 2):

Convert to the format you want:

```
select to_char(col, '990.00')
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ce14843ca6e56517a80e0087e5749834) is a db<>fiddle.

You can control the scale by adjusting the pattern.  For instance, for four decimal places:

```
select to_char(col, '990' || rpad('.', 4 + 1, '0'))
from test;
```

I do not know how to control the result set so the value is number.

Comment: Hi. This solution works only if i know the number of scale, but what if i do not know it? I whould need a simple solution if exists. The final output should be number.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select to_char("a", '000.00') from Table1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/16599a/2

Comment: The output is not a number! I would like to have a numeric output formated as above.